# I need to put all of the lines in a data set into 1 line(python)

Tags: python, line-breaks

so my data looks like this:

```
Test #245, IIH XMOSI - DIGITAL_INPUT_LEAKAGE
Th-: -20.000000 nA Th+:  20.000000 nA - In Limits
Die 1  : XMOSI                     -4.943396 nA Pass (Pin 64, Ch 805)
Pass
```

And I need it to look like this using a python script:

```
Test #245, IIH XMOSI - DIGITAL_INPUT_LEAKAGE Th-: -20.000000 nA Th+:  20.000000 nA - In Limits Die 1  : XMOSI                     -4.943396 nA Pass (Pin 64, Ch 805) Pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is currently in a string (e.g. one called `result`), you can turn it all into one line by removing the newline characters:

```
result.replace("\n","")
```

If you only want to remove newline characters before the word Limits, you could use

```
result.replace("\nLimits", " Limits")
```

We can help with a solution more suited to your particular use case if you can share some details about what the code printing the data currently looks like ( / where the data comes from / how it's stored / what formats it might currently be in)

Comment: I tried your code and it only printed the first line. The data is from a test. The testing machine outputs the data exactly how my question has it, and for right now I just need to get all of that onto one line. I'm not sure if this is even possible in python. The data is basically going to be copied and pasted into this code so it will be outputted on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use join/split:

```
>>> line = "A\n\tB\n\nC\tD\n"
>>> print line
A
    B

C   D

>>> line = ' '.join(line.split())
>>> print line
A B C D
>>>
```